# After Upgrade magento 2.1.8 to 2.2.1 got below error

Tags: magento2

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'head': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 49

Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value '\\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*(\\[A-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*)*'.
Line: 735

Element 'block', attribute 'class': '\\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'blockClassType'.
Line: 735

Element 'remove', attribute 'src_type': The attribute 'src_type' is not allowed.
Line: 778

Element 'block', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed.
Line: 824

Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value '\\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*(\\[A-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*)*'.
Line: 838

Element 'block', attribute 'class': '\\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'blockClassType'.
Line: 838

Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
Line: 890

Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
Line: 891

Element 'remove': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( block, container, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, uiComponent ).
Line: 909

Element 'move': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( action, arguments, block, container, referenceBlock, uiComponent ).
Line: 1293

Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
Line: 1317

Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
Line: 1318
```

Answer (score 3):

## About: [facet 'pattern']

> Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value '\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*(\[A-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*)*'.

This file contain the pattern: 
`/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd:133
'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d\-_]*(\s[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d\-_]*)*'`

Probably you have double spaces in somewhere, **just remove it**.
You can use this link https://regex101.com/ to teste your css classes added on `container` or `block`

## About: The attribute 'src_type'

> Element 'remove', attribute 'src_type': The attribute 'src_type' is not allowed.

According with Magento DevDocs just use `remove` attribute on reference block or container. So is unnecessary the attribute `src_type`.

Read the documentation: [Magento DevDocs - Remove elements](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_remove_elements)

Example:

`<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true" />`

## About Rearrange elements

> Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.

Read the documentation: [Magento DevDocs - Rearrange elements](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_rearrange)

`name` is not part of attributes of `<move>` element. Check the structure: `<move element="" destination="" after=""/>`

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue that many faces when upgrading from 2.1.8 to 2.2.0.

The validation of templates didn't work before. Now it works and all module and layout updates needs to follow the validation rules.

See those threads:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11194
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11116

Do you happen to use Fooman analytics module? If so, their proposal is to update to a later version. Read more here:  http://magento2-support.fooman.co.nz/article/1562-xsd-template-validation-error?

Comment: I got above error when change mode From Production to Developer.

Comment: Do you use Fooman analytics module?

Comment: No, I am use Fooman PrintOrderPdf, I already disable it. But still get same error.

Comment: Fooman is likely only part of the issue. But, have you tried to update it according to their request? It should remove some of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

this exception occurs because you are using an invalid attribute for the element, for example:

**Example 1:**

```
<move name = "form.subscribe"/>
```

Error: the name attribute is not allowed in the move element

Solution: remove the attribute 'name' if use into move element

**Example 2:**

```
<remove name="form.subscribe"/>
```

Error: the remove attribute is not valid

Solution:

```
<referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true" />
```

See the list of allowed attributes in: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_rem

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue.

If you can still access the webadmin Go into the admin and look for those block IDs. Copy those blocks names and contents into their own text file.

Then, delete those blocks from the admin. If you can't access via admin, you can copy and delete them via phpmyadmin or other database method.

Then run these commands in order

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -s standard
```

I was then able to complete the update to 2.2.1 and then just added the blocks I needed back into the store.

The blocks causing the issue for me were calling product lists via widgets, hope it works for you.

Comment: I got above error when change mode From Production to Developer.

Comment: @Bhavesh did you resolve the issue? I am also facing the same issue when tried changing mode from production to developer

Comment: @KalyanChakravarthiV, In my case issue with theme (venustheme) after upgrade theme it solved.

Comment: I too got the solution, in theme xml remove attribute is there for the block, that caused the exception