# Error after changing theme in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I would like to ask for help this is how my index.php looks like after I changed my theme, the backend is working fine.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
Line: 699

Element 'remove': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( block, container, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, uiComponent ).
Line: 714


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
Line: 699

Element 'remove': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( block, container, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, uiComponent ).
Line: 714

#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, '/var/www/html/m...', '%message%\nLine:...')
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(141): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
#6 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:x...', 'layout_merged', false)
#7 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(442): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '<body>\n   <refe...')
#8 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load(Array)
#9 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load()
#10 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
#11 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(254): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#12 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(876): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#13 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#14 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#15 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php(43): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), 'home')
#16 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute(NULL)
#17 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#18 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#20 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#22 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#25 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#31 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#33 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#34 /var/www/html/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#35 {main}
```

Comment: please review this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/203160

Answer (score 0):

In some xml you use the `remove` attribute in other than `<referenceBlock>` and `<referenceContainer>`, Please check your xml's then find the remove attribute where it is used then correct it.

exemple how to remove block:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
...
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true" />
...
    </body>
</page>
```

More information in [Magento DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html)

Comment: Put that code in default.xml